# How to align these two buttons using css?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone kindly help me on how to align these two buttons using css?

```js
 <div>
    <form action="create.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>

    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteItem()" />
    </div>
```

As I did the two buttons are one above the other

Answer (score 1):

```css
.buttons{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons form{
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="buttons">
    <form action="create.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>

    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteItem()" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `class="container"` to div

and `id ="btn"` to button

```
<style>  
.container{  
text-align: center;   
padding-top: 100px;  
}  
#btn{  
font-size: 25px;  
}  
</style>
```

whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Center align button</title>
<style>  
.container{  
text-align: center;   
padding-top: 100px;  
}  
#btn{  
font-size: 25px;  
}  
</style> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="create.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
<br />

    <input type="button" id ="btn" value="Delete" onclick="deleteItem()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show me the full code?

Comment: yes I have added whole code. now you just need to add css

Comment: you can also add id ="btn" to add input